# Why Go doesn't show memory-reordering?

Tags: c++, memory, concurrency, go

I'm reading preshing's blog [Memory Reordering Caught in the Act](http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/), and reproduced memory-reordering by his [example code](http://preshing.com/files/ordering.zip)

Then I wonder if I could reproduce memory-reordering by Go, so I wrote the example code in go, but memory-reordering is not shown in Go.

I'm writing to share some findings.

And could you help explain why Go could not get memory-reordering? Thanks.

Example code in Go:

```
 package main

    import (
            "fmt"
            "math/rand"
    )

    var x, y, r1, r2 int
    var detected = 0

    func randWait() {
            for rand.Intn(8) != 0 {
            }
    }

    func main() {
            beginSig1 := make(chan bool, 1)
            beginSig2 := make(chan bool, 1)
            endSig1 := make(chan bool, 1)
            endSig2 := make(chan bool, 1)
            go func() {
                    for {
                            <-beginSig1
                            randWait()
                            x = 1
                            r1 = y
                            endSig1 <- true
                    }
            }()
            go func() {
                    for {
                            <-beginSig2
                            randWait()
                            y = 1
                            r2 = x
                            endSig2 <- true
                    }
            }()
            for i := 1; ; i = i + 1 {
                    x = 0
                    y = 0
                    beginSig1 <- true
                    beginSig2 <- true
                    <-endSig1
                    <-endSig2
                    if r1 == 0 && r2 == 0 {
                            detected = detected + 1
                            fmt.Println(detected, "reorders detected after ", i, "iterations")
                    }
            }
    }
```

The assembly code (by "ndisasm -b 32") show different between C++ vs Go

- Assembly code from C++

  ```
  00000CF0  C705520300000100  mov dword [0x352],0x1     //X=1
           -0000
  00000CFA  8B0550030000      mov eax,[0x350]     
  00000D00  89054E030000      mov [0x34e],eax      //r1=Y
  ```
- Assembly code from Go

  ```
  000013EA  48                dec eax
  000013EB  C70425787F170001  mov dword [0x177f78],0x1     //x=1
           -000000
  000013F6  48                dec eax
  000013F7  8B1C25807F1700    mov ebx,[0x177f80]
  000013FE  48                dec eax
  000013FF  891C25687F1700    mov [0x177f68],ebx          //r1=Y
  00001406  48                dec eax
  ```

it seems Go uses `dec eax` around access of shared memory, but it make no sense that `dec eax` can prevent memory-reordering

1. The [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) Volume 3, Section 8.2 shows the cases that could prevent memory-reordering, but `dec eax` isn't included...
2. I tried to add `dec eax` as margin of shared-memory-access in C code, and memory-reordering is still there.

By now, I have no clue about the reason. Please help me on it, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see a call to set GOMAXPROCs anywhere?  If you don't call it you'll be running on just one CPU which won't ever show re-ordering: http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS

**Update**: In Go 1.5 (Released 2015/08/19) and later you no longer need to set GOMAXPROCS - Go defaults to using all your CPUs.

Comment: Thank you, @Nick. I missed GOMAXPROC... Go got memory-reordering after add GOMAXPROCS.

Answer (score 0):

The Go memory model is not that of C or C++.

Have a look at http://golang.org/ref/mem which describes the "Happens Before" HB relation and how it relates to channels. Note that the current implementations may have more HB than required by the memory model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `mov ebx,[0x177f80]` instruction makes the difference.

It loads `ebx`, which means `mov [0x177f68],ebx` is dependent on it, and can't be moved ahead of it. So if there's reordering, both moves that use `ebx` must be reordered together. I think this is not allowed - the x86_64 architecutre doesn't reorder reads with other reads (not 100% sure on this).

Comment: Thank you, @ugoren. You're correct that read is not reordered with other reads in x86 arch. Here, the reordering is between `mov dword [0x177f78],0x1 ` and `mov [0x177f68],ebx`, one read after one write.